# How scala handle nested parametrization?

Tags: scala

Consider an example:

```
public def someFunc(f: (One Pair Two Pair Three) => Future[Two]) : SomeResultType = {...}

case class One(...)
case class Two(...)
case class Three(...)
```

Pair is `scala.Predef#Pair`
What does `scala.Predef#Pair` mean? As I know I can write function calls in scala like this `println "string"` but in that case token are types. What does the actual type of expression `One Pair Two Pair Three`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `REPL` to get your answer:

```
scala> def ttt: Int Pair Long Pair String = ???
ttt: Pair[Pair[Int,Long],String]
```

Type `A B C` means `B[A, C]` in `scala`.

So `One Pair Two Pair Three` means `Pair[One,Two] Pair Three` means `Pair[Pair[One, Two], Three]`.

`Pair` is just a type alias to `Tuple2`.

Note that `Pair` is [deprecated](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L230), you should use `Tuple2` instead: `((One, Two), Three)`.